# implementing a zooming algorithm like in photoshop

Tags: zooming, photoshop

i am developing a editor for 2d game modeling with open gl and i want to implement zooming into it. What i would like to archive is a similar zooming algorithm that is used in photoshop. Which goes something like this:

- you have 21 different levels of zoom (10 for zoom in, 10 for zoom out and 1 for neutral)
- when you zoom in levels are: 200%, 300%, 400%, 500%, 600%, 700%, 800%, 1200%, 3200%
- when you zoom out levels are: 66,7%, 50%, 33%, 25%, 16,7%, 12,5%, 9,1%, 8,3%, 6,25%, 5%

The problem that i am having is i have no idea how to calculate these numbers.. So i was wondering if anyone knows if there is a specific formula to calculate the levels of zoom or is this just something that is hardcoded into photoshop?

Comment: The 1:1 or 100%-view in Photoshop has a technical reason as one pixel of the screen is exactly one pixel in the image to be edited. For your game editor, is there also something like that? How is the 1:1-view defined?

Comment: the same way, 1px of screen is one pixel of a an object.

Comment: OpenGL usually doesn't work with pixel but with float-vectors. Is it the texture of the object or does the code make sure to have objects with integral bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess this is hardcoded. Those numbers are adjusted for specific use cases for the users of Photoshop. In case of zoom out:

- 1:2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/6, 1/8, 1/11, 1/12, 1/16, 1/20
- same for zoom in. specific for the needs of the users.

It is therefore more of a question for the User Experience than about an algorithm.